# Ensuring avoidance of malpractices while committing in Git

Tags: git, github

In case of Git, we set user.name and user.email before performing any commits on local machine.

My question is - how Git actually make sure that these parameters are valid?
What if any team member maliciously set user.name and user.email of another team member and perform some bad commits?

Any protection provided by Git for such malpractices or this protection has to be set at the level of certain guidelines defined by project management?

Comment: Git doesn't care, those are arbitrary values that anyone can set to anything they want. If you want these values (and others in a commit) to be verified, make sure to [sign your commits](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits).

Comment: And since you mention "project management": your git workflow should involve pull requests of some form, which involve verified users giving their ok for a specific change going into the relevant branches. **Those** actions require user authentication and are what you should worry about. Think of git commit attributes as roughly as useful/secure as code comments: they can be very useful, but you can't really stop anyone from *lying* in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign the commit using GPG, so that the commit can be validated that it is coming from trusted source

Read more
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification